# Changing background image of div while hovering list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

Here is my **html**:

```
<li><a href=""><div class="arrow"></div>List Item</a></li>
```

How can I change background image of class "arrow" while hovering "List Item" with a mouse ?
Where class arrow is just a navigation image that goes in front of every list item.

Here's my **css**:

```
.arrow {
background: transparent url('../images/arrow.png') center center no-repeat;
width:16px;
height:16px;
float: left;
padding:0;
margin-right:1em;
}

.arrow:hover {
background: transparent url('../images/arrow_hover.png') center center no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
li:hover .arrow {
    background: transparent url('../favicon.png') center center no-repeat;
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UN7DF/)